# Error while compiling nodemcu ESP8266 board

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I have tried to upload a simple code onto my esp8266 board and I undergo this error :

esptool.py v2.8
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 2c:3a:e8:01:1d:3e
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 267168 bytes to 196959...
Writing at 0x00000000... (7 %)Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in 
esptool.main(cmdline)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 2938, in main
operation_func(esp, args)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 2374, in write_flash
esp.flash_defl_block(block, seq, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * ratio * 2)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 104, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 672, in flash_defl_block
self.ESP_FLASH_DEFL_DATA, struct.pack('<IIII', len(data), seq, 0, 0) + data, self.checksum(data), timeout=timeout)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 369, in check_command
val, data = self.command(op, data, chk, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 337, in command
self.write(pkt)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 300, in write
self._port.write(buf)
File "/home/tarun/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py", line 552, in write
raise writeTimeoutError
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
the selected serial port serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
does not exist or your board is not connected

This is the error I undergo. I have checked twice for the port and the baud rate(115200). Kindly help me solve this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your board how you can flash it. Here https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php/Basics:_Connecting_and_flashing_the_ESP8266 is a very detailed guide about how to flash.

Especially the Section "Some basics about flashing" could solve your problem https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php/Basics:_Connecting_and_flashing_the_ESP8266#Some_basics_about_flashing

> The ESP has four inputs that manage the startup behaviour. These
> setting are necessary to flash the chip!
>
> The GPIO15 pin should always be set to "low". Use a 10KOhm resistor
> between GPIO15 and ground.
>
> GPIO2 should be pulled to "high". Use a 10KOhm resistor between GPIO2
> and 3.3V (Vcc).
>
> The GPIO0 setting now decides between run mode and flash mode. Connect
> a 10 KOhm resistor between 3.3V (Vcc) and GPIO0. This sets the ESP8266
> into run mode.
>
> Now you may connect the GPIO0 directly to ground for flashing.
>
> The fourth is the "reset" pin. It should be on "high", so put a 10
> KOhm resistor between Vcc and reset pin.
>
> For all ESP's besides nodeMCU and WeMOS there is a "CH-PG" pin. It's
> an "enable" pin you may use to switch off the whole ESP-Chip. Put a
> 10KOhm resistor between CH_PG and Vcc to keep the ESP running at all.
>
> Devices with an embedded ESP-Chip (Sonoff basic or 4ch for example)
> will have these resistors on board. Just GPIO0 has to be set to ground
> with a jumper bridge or via a pushbutton.